# How to ensure that a generic type can take a generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Apology for the confusing title, as I do not know how to put it clearly.
I am trying to achieve a way to create a generic type, which will be used later to pass a generic type.

To clear away the confusion, given these two interfaces:

```
interface Field<T> {
  value: T;
  hasError: boolean;
}

interface Record {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

And these inheritances of `Field`

```
interface FooField<T> extends Field<T> {
  foo: () => void;
}

interface BarField<T> extends Field<T> {
  bar: () => void;
}
```

I would like to generate new types of `Record` of the following type:

```
interface FooRecord {
  id: FooField<number>;
  name: FooField<string>;
}

interface BarRecord {
  id: BarField<number>;
  name: BarField<string>;
}
```

The most intuitive, but incorrect, way of doing this would be as follow:

```
type MagicRecord<XField extends Field> = {
  [K in keyof Record]: XField<Record[K]>;
};

type FooRecord = MagicRecord<FooField>;
type BarRecord = MagicRecord<BarField>;
```

How can I do this, if even possible, correctly with typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), which are not supported in TypeScript as of v3.5. Anything you do here will be a workaround involving some amount of code duplication.

Here's one possible workaround.  First of all, note that I'm not going to use the name `Record` as it collides with the name of a [built-in type alias](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1452-L1454).  I'll switch to `MyRecord`:

```
interface MyRecord {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

So let's have a lookup table `FieldLookup<T>` which maps from the name of the generic type to the generic type itself specified with `T`.  This table will need one entry for every subtype of `Field<T>` you want to support:

```
interface FieldLookup<T> extends Record<keyof FieldLookup<any>, Field<T>> {
  Field: Field<T>;
  FooField: FooField<T>;
  BarField: BarField<T>;
}
```

Then we can define `MagicRecord<XField>` which takes the name of the generic field as a string literal:

```
type MagicRecord<XField extends keyof FieldLookup<any>> = {
  [K in keyof MyRecord]: FieldLookup<MyRecord[K]>[XField]
};

type FooRecord = MagicRecord<"FooField">;
type BarRecord = MagicRecord<"BarField">;
```

So that works.  We could go a little further and make it so that you don't need to use or care about the type names, by implementing a reverse lookup for `FieldLookup`:

```
type ReverseLookup<F extends Field<any>> = {
  [K in keyof FieldLookup<any>]: FieldLookup<any>[K] extends F ? K : never
}[keyof FieldLookup<any>];
```

And then `MagicRecord<XField>` would be used as your original version except that `XField` has to be a concrete type:

```
type MagicRecord2<XField extends Field<any>> = MagicRecord<
  ReverseLookup<XField>
>;

type FooRecord2 = MagicRecord2<FooField<any>>; // FooField<any>, not FooField
type BarRecord2 = MagicRecord2<BarField<any>>; // BarField<any>, not BarField
```

This also works.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCYB4AqAfMgN4BQyyAbnJgK4QBcy+A3BcgBZwDOAolCgB7KMwBGQoZghwQ7AL5kyoSLEQoAsgE8AShAQjspDsGzMQdALZjo7SiDiWmyHmCigA5gqUro8JGiS6Fh4RMgQAB6QINg8aBg4BMTklDCSzAAUAJTIALzEVEKm3srgfurIAEJwUMGJYZHRsfEhScaUYjWZOfnURdglvmoBddgAMpIA1nQADm2NEDFxegZQeJMQWkIwLTgTQtNzslqEADS7oYTJHKPMo0l2gUK3T-dEj9W1CWZVNW+EJTAWhmmjgHmACBWhlwAA1RuEootmhstjtRvtDrhjlc8u1kABtADSyFAyBR22Q2ihawAundvhjZrgqfpDESaYR8XDvjSyPJ2GQgSCntSjLlKWCIaLcAAiVBBb4ygGC4EoT6i3EaSWQ1lrWWfUZKgVClB6KjQHgQRlzVAIppxe7Y4jilIE4mk8lohlTJnYukXa1YkAndl2pEO5AAfmQxPMEHNUD5+M9AZ9R2DhBpxtVEvBOtW2AATLD4Qslhcgydnbmpbq8BwzRarWmS99CGRlSrhfKhKLC5rtX3cD3HRnlSbflA+wO80ODd9K1d2EA)